# pickle saving pygame Surface (python)

Tags: python, pygame, pickle, geometry-surface

I tried to save a pygame.Surface but it doesn't let me, error

> TypeError: can't pickle Surface objects

I can make it save surfaces?
Or maybe there is another module that can save it ?

EXPLANATION:

```
a = pygame.Surface( (5,5) )
file = open("hello", "w")
pickle.dump(a, file)
```

I have classes which saves in them Surfaces.

Comment: What do you mean by "save" the surface? Set it to a variable? Please post the code that is giving you this error.

Comment: You can pickle the filepath or key to a dict of loaded textures. You don't want/need to pickle the actual Surface object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As monkey said: You don't want to pickle a surface. But if you really need to save that surfaces' content than use the [`pygame.image.save()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save) function.

If you prefer your surface not to be an actual image file (for whatever reason) you could use the [`pygame.image.tostring()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.tostring) function which lets you convert the surfaces' content into a stringbuffer.

Answer (score 0):

now `pygame.image.tobytes` and `pygame.image.frombytes` is also supported.